# Calculating total quantities

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where a bill of materials exported in the Excel pulls in the 'Level', 'Item' and 'Qty'. In order to calculate the total qty for an item in the BoM it is necessary to multiply up the quantities by the quantity in the parent levels. I have shown this below manually but due to the size of the real data set i was wondering if there is a method available using VBA to calculate the Total Qty values?

```
 Level        Item         Qty       Total Qty
    1           A           1           1
    1           B           2           2
    2           C           3           6
    2           D           1           2
    2           E           2           4
    3           F           5           20
    3           G           3           12
    2           H           2           4
    3           I           1           4
    2           J           1           2
    2           K           3           6
    1           L           2           2
    1           M           1           1
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you get total quantity a little more? Perhaps next to your column, add the "formula" you used to calculate it.  (How'd you get 20 for Item F?)

Comment: how are you getting 20 for level 3 F?

Comment: Level 3 'F' is used in Level 2 'E'. The bom requires a total of 4 x 'E' therefore the total qty for 'F' is 4 x 5.

Comment: The bom requires 4 x 'E' as it is used in Level 1 'B'. There are 2 x 'B' and each 'B' requires 2 x 'E'. Therefopre the total for 'E' is 2 x 2

Comment: So an item at level x is part of the last item at level (x-1)?

Comment: Yes, sorry i havent explained it too well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a UDF to use.

Paste it in a module in the workbook you are using.

```
Function qtyfind(level As Range) As Double
    Dim i&, temp&, qtyClm&, tQtyClm&

    'Change the Column name to match if different
    qtyClm = WorksheetFunction.Match("QTY", Range("1:1"))
    tQtyClm = WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL QTY", Range("1:1"))

    If level = 1 Then
        temp = Cells(level.Row, qtyClm)
    Else
        For i = level.Row To 2 Step -1 'loops bottom up

            If Cells(i, level.Column) = (level.value - 1) Then
                temp = Cells(i, tQtyClm) * Cells(level.Row, qtyClm)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    qtyfind = temp
End Function
```

Then call it like this in the first cell and copy down:

[image]

Comment: @user3673417 Glad to help. If it worked then please mark as correct.  Also I changed it encase the column order is different on your actual worksheet than the simplified one shown.